# How to recover zfs pool when root fs fails

Tags: data-recovery, freebsd, zfs

I have a FreeBSD 8.0 amd64 box w/ 1 ATA drive for system and 4 SATA drives as a RAIDZ pool. The ATA drive isn't mirrored nor part of any pool, but also doesn't hold any valuable data.

How can I recover my zpool if this ATA drive fails for any reason, but assume my RAIDZ vdev SATA drives remain intact? Should I also use at least a mirror configuration for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to upgrade my RAIDz pool which was created using FreeNAS (which uses FreeBSD) to OpenSolaris.  I believe I needed to do a zpool import -f {name of pool} and it checked the drives and was able to determine which were part of the pool.

So I hadn't recovered from an OS failure, but I did swap my pool drive without doing an export, and I would guess a failure of the OS drive would be similar.

So in short if the FreeBSD drive fails, when you replace and reload, I believe all you would need to do is a zpool import to reattach the pool to that machine.

As far as mirroring the OS drive, I think that is always a good idea.  Another alternative is having something like Ghost or Acronis image of the OS drive.  That way when you do the bare metal rebuild you can lay down a preconfigured image.  In that case, the OS may not be any the wiser about the pool being previously created.

Good luck.